# Branch IO SDK change domain breaks link

Tags: ios, testflight, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using branch.io for deep linking. A few days back I have installed the build from the Testflight and tested some links and it was working perfectly. It opened the application.

But when I checked today the links goes to the app store instead of opening the application. What might be the issue? Also when I open the page in my mobile it shows "FILE NOT FOUND".

Links I use:
http://deeplink.notarycam.com/company

Solved the issue, because I changed the link subdomain I forget to change in the associated domains.

I create a single link and change the query params and handle on the iOS app side.

So, link generated before changing the domains were working perfectly and now links do open the app but I don't receive params as I received before. 3 params are received in branch object and one shows that **+non_branch_link**.

But I generated a new link and changing params works perfectly. Seems there are some issues in Branch SDK.

Comment: Could you post an example link that isn't working? You might also want to review the Branch [Universal Links troubleshooting section](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#troubleshooting-universal-links)

Comment: @AlexBauer Updated with link

Comment: @AlexBauer Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: **this is expected**. Changing your link domain will cause all previous Branch links to stop working, and we strongly recommend not changing your link domain for this reason.

Comment: Hi @AlexBauer,.. I need to change the domain, how can I update the links manually? OR what else should I do?